# AES Encrypting a password field in django using a snippet from djangosnippets

Tags: django, django-models, aes, extending

I am attempting to use this snippet: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1095/ on a model I am building-  I am defining things as:

```
first = models.TextField()
last = models.TextField()
email = models.EmailField(default=None)
screen = models.TextField()
password = models.EncryptedCharField()
icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/')
```

When I attempt to validate the model (running syncdb) it gives me an error that states that the "EncryptedCharField" is not defined.

I have the code from that snippet present in my model.py file- is this incorrect?  do i need to implement this snippet elsewhere, or have it extend a different class?

Comment: I am attempting to follow the docs listed here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-model-fields/ but where do these files go?  the django docs don't say much about where these should live in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that `EncryptedCharField` is not defined in `models`. If it's defined in the current module then you should not be trying to reference it from a different module.

Comment: But the model i'm defining and the declarations for the encrypted strings are in the same model.py file- the same 'place'. Where -should- this logic go?